# Is there a way to execute code in blazor component inside html tags?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

What I am would like to do is something like this:

```
<input type="text"
@if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Element.Placeholder))
{
   placeholder="@Element.Placeholder"
}
/>
```

And I want to do that with many properties like maxlength, value etc.
The best solution I came up with is using MarkUpString to do the above and then render it. I was wondering if there is a way to use if's inside an html tag so my code will be cleaner and easier to modify. Please be lenient, I'm new to programming and especially Blazor. Thanks

*Edit: I want this component to be editable from another component too.

Comment: I'm offering this as a comment, as I believe Shaun's answer is good, but there is an additional thing to note: in the example you gave in your quesiton, you could simply not bother with the conditional - and assign `placeholder="@Element.Placeholder"` - Blazor will remove the attribute if Placeholder is null. However, the same is not true for non-nullables, so stick with Shaun's answer :)

Comment: That's what i ended up doing. I want this input to be editable from another component and I get an error with @attributes. I changed int values to int? so they are nullable and seems to work fine for now.

Comment: @DimitriosTsimaras.  Hi, if your happy with the answer then tick the Answer.  I don't give a damn about the points, but it marks the question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@attributes`.  I've shown a very simple code example below setting the style.

```
<button @attributes="this.ButtonAttributes">Red Button</button>
```

```
@code{

  private Dictionary<string, object> ButtonAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();

  protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    ButtonAttributes.Add("class", "btn btn-danger");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  }

}
```